# How to find the max difference in array when the first number indicates the last index

Tags: c#, arrays

You can compare only with the previous values
For example: (5,3,4,6,2,10)

```
n = 5
4 -(3)
5-(4,3)...
```

In this case the answer is 8
And here (4, 3,2,1) - the answer is 0
I tried this but it seem I'm missing something

```
    public static int ReverseFindDiffenrce(int[] arr)
    {

        if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1)
            return -1;

     if (arr.Any(i => i < 0)) return -1; 
        int max_diff = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0] ; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i -1 ; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[i] - arr[j] > max_diff)
                    max_diff = arr[i] - arr[j];
            }
        }

        return max_diff;

    }
```

Looking for more efficient answer.

Comment: Why the answer is 0 for the list (4, 3,2,1)? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @deepu, 2-3 then  1-2 and 1-3. All < to default diff =0

Comment: And an variable for arr[i] - arr[j], instead of computing it twice.

Comment: @Drag and Drop the term as you wrote it. So you suggest to remove the any condition and to replace it with ?

Comment: Sorry I miss the point the Arr[0], should always indicate Lenght -1. Meaning that you always have a O(2N-1) instead of O(N). because of any.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= arr[0] ; ++i){ if (arr[i]<0) ... }`, or keep I2 and test arr[1] solo

Comment: @DragandDrop `if (arr[i]<0)` unnecessary . ` if (arr.Any(i => i < 0)) return -1; ` eliminate it for negative elements.

Comment: Is it better to remove the double for loop and the Any condition and just to add a test for negative, find min value and max value and add another if about the index?

Comment: @Sheanan, I don't understand your last comment. Add benchmark with code. If you have a 3rd algo/optimisation. you can post your own answer i will benchmark it if you ping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my test it's just a ~20% reduction, loop only once eliminate the `Any()`.

Arr[0] is always test as it should be equals to Lenght - 1
Arr[1] is tested as it's not in the I=2 loop.

```
public static int ReverseFindDiffenrceWithoutAny(int[] arr)
{
    if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1 || arr[1] < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int max_diff = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0]; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[i] - arr[j] > max_diff)
            {
                max_diff = arr[i] - arr[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return max_diff;
}
```

Benchmark Result, last column is the % based on the original function :

```
// * Summary *

            Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
------------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|
      DiffOriginal | 366.6 ns | 4.802 ns | 4.492 ns |    0   %        
           DiffTom | 272.2 ns | 2.766 ns | 2.587 ns |  -25.75%
 DiffOriginalNoAny | 340.1 ns | 2.474 ns | 2.193 ns |  - 7.22%
      DiffTomNoAny | 217.4 ns | 1.878 ns | 1.756 ns |  -40.69%
```

Methode used :

```
public class ArrayDiff
{
    public static int[] arr => new[] { 5, 3, 4, 6, 2, 10 };

    [Benchmark]
    public static int DiffOriginalNoAny()
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1 || arr[1] < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int max_diff = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0]; ++i)
        {
            if (arr[i] < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[i] - arr[j] > max_diff)
                {
                    max_diff = arr[i] - arr[j];
                }
            }
        }

        return max_diff;
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public static int DiffOriginal()
    {

        if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (arr.Any(i => i < 0))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int max_diff = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0]; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[i] - arr[j] > max_diff)
                {
                    max_diff = arr[i] - arr[j];
                }
            }
        }
        return max_diff;
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public static int DiffTom()
    {

        if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (arr.Any(i => i < 0))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int max_diff = 0;
        int min = arr[1];

        for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0]; ++i)
        {
            if (arr[i] < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (arr[i] < min)
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }

            if (arr[i] - min > max_diff)
            {
                max_diff = arr[i] - min;
            }
        }
        return max_diff;
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public static int DiffTomNoAny()
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1 || arr[1] < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int max_diff = 0;
        int min = arr[1];

        for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0]; ++i)
        {
            if (arr[i] < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (arr[i] < min)
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }

            if (arr[i] - min > max_diff)
            {
                max_diff = arr[i] - min;
            }
        }
        return max_diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: I listen to your advice and removed the Any.
and adjusted the solution so there is only one **for** loop
and a lot of **if** but is seem to work so thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is more efficient to cache the min of the left part.

```
public static int ReverseFindDiffenrce(int[] arr)
{

    if (arr == null || arr.Length < 3 || arr[0] != arr.Length - 1)
        return -1;

    if (arr.Any(i => i < 0)) return -1; 
    int max_diff = 0;
    int min = arr[1];
    for (int i = 2; i <= arr[0] ; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
             min = arr[i];

        if (arr[i] - min > max_diff)
            max_diff = arr[i] - min;
    }

    return max_diff;
}
```

Comment: Add BenchMark information with and without the `Any()` in both your algo and the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update, there was a mistake and negative numbers were possible as well as arr[0] was not added on input as the original question suggested and was just part of array:
In this case this was the correct answer:

```
        public static int GetMaxDiff(int[] arr)
        {
            if (arr == null || arr.Length < 2 )             
                return -1;

            int max_diff = -1;
            int min = arr[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (arr[i] < 0)
                    return -1;

                if (arr[i] < min)
                    min = arr[i];

                if (arr[i] - min > max_diff)
                    max_diff = arr[i] - min;

            }
            if (max_diff == 0) return -1;
            return max_diff;
        }
```

thanks for help it helped :)